# How to embed the body of a live unit test function as example usage with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, testing, doxygen

**I want to embed the body of a live unit test function as the example.**

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511878/in-doxygen-how-can-include-a-snippet-by-function-name-from-example-code-instead)

In doxygen, we can show example usage:

- with an entire .c file using the @example instruction.
- with a snipper using the @code instruction
- somehow with the @snippet directive + EXAMPLE_PATH (can't get it to work)

`@example` won't work because I don't have just one unit test per c file.  My test files have a bunch of unit tests in them organized as functions.

`@code` means I have to write some code that isn't going to get compiled or actually executed.  (In Python, there are doctests -- which is the reverse of what I'm looking for because doctests can be actually executed as a unit test.  Something like that would be fine here.)

`@snippet` might work. It looks like we would decorate the unit test and that makes it into a snippet.  I can't get this to work. (see below)

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * @brief Sets the values to zero
 *
 */
void set_to_zero(my_type_t *t)
{
    t->x = 0;
    t->y = 0;
}
```

... in another test_suite_1.c file, where I have lots of unit tests.  Here's one ...

```
int test_set_to_zero()
{
    my_type_t t;
    set_to_zero(t);
    MYASSERT(t.x == 0);
    MYASSERT(t.y == 0);
}
```

I would like just this unit test, from my test_suite_1.c file (not *all* unit tests in the whole file) to appear in the documentation as example usage of this particular function.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can keep practicing DRY.  The unit test is essentially a pretty good example of basic usage.

**Is there some directive like:  `@embed_function_body_here<test_set_to_zero>`**

Going back to `@snippet`.  As I said, it didn't work.  Here's what I tried to do with the `@snippet` directive:

My unit tests are in a \test folder.  There are separate .c files containing unit tests (e.g. test_suite_1.c, test_suite_2.c, etc

... in test_suite_1.c ...

```
//! [Zero Test]
int test_set_to_zero()
{
    my_type_t t;
    set_to_zero(t);
    MYASSERT(t.x == 0);
    MYASSERT(t.y == 0);
}
//! [Zero Test]
```

... in regular_code.c ...

```
/**
 * @brief Sets the values to zero
 * @snippet test\test_suite_1.c Zero Test
 *
 */
void set_to_zero(my_type_t *t)
{
    t->x = 0;
    t->y = 0;
}
```

... in doxyfile ...

```
...
EXAMPLE_PATH = test
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE = YES
...
```

This whole `@snippet` endeavor doesn't work.  Nothing shows in the resulting html where the snippet should be.

Comment: I got the snippet to work. After the brief command either put a . (when JAVADOC_BRIEF is enabled) or an empty line (i.e. line with just a *) to end the brief, now [Zero test] is seen as continuation of @brief (as shown in my case with the error message: warning: block marked with [Zero Test.] for \snippet should appear twice in file test\test_suite_1.c. Set also the EXAMPLE path to the path leading to the test directory (not including the test)Small remark don't use \ (backslash) in the path makes it less portable and also might lead strange effects when seen as escape character.

Comment: Perfect!  If you'll write this as a complete answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the error says it's looking for `[Zero Test.]`, and not `[Zero Test]`.  This is because your snippet is actually part of the brief, and it looks like a brief is automatically terminated with a `.` regardless if you put one.

The snippet is actually looking for the markers `[Zero Test.]`; if you put the `.` in the marker, it'll actually work.  But your solution is better, just terminate the brief! :)

To be completely honest, it was your comment that led me to solve the issue (which I was having too); [010110110101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451007/010110110101) is right, you should get credit for this.